# VS 2010 - Missing project templates ( vsInstallTemplates not found )

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, configuration, project-template

SharePoint project templates are not showing up in our VS 2010 installed on the server (SP is already installed & running in that machine).

After researching a little bit, I've copied the missing .zip files from another machine, and pasted them inside "{VS Installation Path}/Common7/IDE/Project Templates".

Now I'm supposed to run "devenv /VsInstallTemplates" from the VS Command Prompt with administrator privileges.

The problem is that when I type that ... it doesn't recognise "VsInstallTemplates" :S Error says: "Unknown switch". It's not a typo since I've written it like 100 times.

Searched in Google but it seems like no one has already run into "Unknown Switch" problem ...

Any hints??